# Example of a projective bimodule with isomorphic left and right duals

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, monoidal-categories

What is an example of a non-free finitely generated $R$-bimodule $M$ satisfying

i)   $M$ is projective as both a left and right $R$-module

ii)  the right dual $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R)$ and the left dual $_R\mathrm{Hom}(M,R)$ are isomorphic as bimodules,

where $R$ is a noncommutative unital algebra defined over a field $k$ with non-zero characteristic.

Comment: Why does $M=R$ not work?

Comment: I guess I want a non-trivial example.

Comment: You mean that $M$ is not free?

Comment: yes, I have put this in the question

Comment: Just a minor rant about terminology. $M=R$ is not free *as a bimodule*. Also, a bimodule that is projective on the left and on the right is not necessarily a projective bimodule.

Answer (score 2):

Take $G$ a nonabelian finite group of size coprime to $p$, and $k$ a field of characteristic $p>0$. Then $k[G]$ is semisimple (Maschke's theorem), so every module on left or right is projective.

In particular, take $\underline{k}$ to be the trivial representation of $G$. So this is a bimodule projective on both sides, and $\mathrm{Hom}_G(\underline{k}, k[G])={_G\mathrm{Hom}}(\underline{k}, k[G])=\underline{k}$, as bimodules (both of these being naturally the same subspace of $k[G]$, i.e. $\langle\sum_{g \in G}g\rangle$).

... This satisfies all the criteria of the question; somehow, however, this still does not feel as if it should count for a *non-trivial* example.

Comment: In fact, for any group algebra $k[G]$ of a finite group, semisimple or not, and for any bimodule $M$, the left dual and right dual are isomorphic. And there are plenty of natural bimodules that are projective on both sides: e.g., $k[G]\otimes_{k[H]}k[G]$ for a subgroup $H\leq G$.